# Javascript AutoFill

Tags: javascript

OK so basically I am trying to auto fill passwords on a website and also bring the browser to that website. Yes I know chrome(browser I use) does that but I am to cool. The code below takes me to the website but doesn't fill the passwords. P.S. It is a book mark I am running it from.

```
javascript:window.location.assign("https://sso.rumba.pearsoncmg.com/sso/login?profile=snp&k12int=true&service=http%3a%2f%2fschool.pearsoned.com%2fPegasus%2fRumbaSsoHandler.ashx%3fprofile%3dsnp"); document.getElementById("username").value = "username"; documen.getElementById("password").value="password";
```

Comment: You need to write an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the page's location the javascript stops running as the javascript was running on the previous page. So document.getElementById doesn't get executed.

Comment: Is there any way to get around that

Comment: You would need to write an extension to get around that. But it will only work in browsers that have that extension installed. Is it just for your own use or do you want others to also use it?

Comment: Just for my use. What language would that be in. I kinda know a little of all of them. Mainly c++, java, javascript, and html

Comment: That depends on the browser. Normally a kind of javascript.